# Python program slows computer after being executed multiple times

Tags: python, memory, tkinter

I am repeatedly running my program with IDLE for debugging purposes, but it seems that over time I'm creating some sort of memory issue that's clogging up my computer.  What types of errors with a Tkinter GUI written in python could cause this?

If that isn't a common source of problems, my imports are as follows:

```
import copy
import pickle
import re
import requests as req
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
```

The other source that I can think of is requests.  I'm using both post and get, but primarily post.  Are there any mistakes to be made with these methods that would cause a computer to slow?

My computer remains slow after I have closed all related windows.  This only happens after I've been running and stopping the program multiple times.  This is not an issue with the program itself being slow.

Edit:  Looks like the issue is something to do with running through IDLE.  I've run it pretty extensively through the command prompt with no issue.  Weird.

Comment: Are you sure that the program is terminating and not hanging trying to do something after it should have exited? Try running `ps aux | grep python` if you are on linux/os x and see how many instances of python you have running.

Comment: python has gc in-built, so very less chances of memory clean up issues. If you starting any background processes as part of program. Make sure you close/kill all of them in all cases of positive/failure cases. Also make all the back ground process are clean up. Also have look at ps(in case of linux)/task manager( in windows) to see if there are mulitple instances of same executable or binary running

Comment: Does this happen without IDLE?

Comment: I haven't tried it without idle yet, so I'll give that a go on Monday when I get the chance.  I have checked the Task Manager (windows 7), and I didn't see any extraneous processes.  It's fairly small and I don't spawn any other processes, because that's a little beyond me at the moment.

Comment: I've gave it a go without IDLE today.  I didn't notice the same slow down as before, however I also didn't get the opportunity to do as much as I normally do.  I'll keep looking into it over the course of the week and see if I can't hammer down a reason.  Or at least narrow it down to that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only times that it gets slow is when you are using idle and doing it a lot of times. It may just be idle and using a different editor like pycharm ([Download here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) will fix it.
If that doesn't work it doesn't really matter because you would only run it tons of times with idle while testing it and users wont run it nearly as much and they will run it with command prompt most likely.